# Rearranging a data set to create one with lags (Past obervations)

Tags: r, dataset, matlab

Let's say the original data set has 100 observations

X1, X2, X3, --- , X100

Now I want to rearrange the data as follows and create a new data set

**Current_State**  **Lag1** **Lag2** **Lag3** **Lag4** **Lag5**

**X100**               *X99        X98     X97      X96    X95*

**X99**                *X98        X97     X96      X95    X94*

**X98**                *X97        X96     X95      X94    X93*

**X97**                *X96        X95     X94      X93    X92*

.
.
.

**X6**                *X5        X4     X3      X2    X1*

Is there anyway to do this simple manipulation in r or matlab rather than doing a series of for loops.

Comment: Since this question focuses on programming, it's off topic on this site. But, it would be a good fit for stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab

You can build an index with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (broadcasting) to generate the desired result:

```octave
x = [10 34 22 5 17 48 56 6 19]; % data
L = 5; % number of lags
result = x((end-L:-1:1).'+(L:-1:0));
```

This gives a result in which

- the row defines the current sample, and
- each column is a lag.

Example:

```
>> x
x =
    10    34    22     5    17    48    56     6    19
>> result
result =
    19     6    56    48    17     5
     6    56    48    17     5    22
    56    48    17     5    22    34
    48    17     5    22    34    10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the equivalent of a loop in any language, but it can be disguised and abbreviated.  In `R`:

```
x <- 1:100 # Example of the data
k <- 5     # Specify number of lags
#
# Here is the computation.  It creates each column successively, putting
# them (automatically) into a matrix.  The rest is just cosmetic--turning
# the matrix into a dataframe and naming its variables.
#
y <- rev(x)
X <- as.data.frame(sapply(0:k, function(i) y[1:(length(y)-k)+i]))
colnames(X) <- paste0("Lag", 0:k)
```